# Parameters to query snmp V3 agent

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to write a c code using net-snmp library to query snmp V3 agents.I wanted to know what are the parameters that I will have to use to query the agent.

Does the parameter list depend upon agents or is it same for all agent?

Comment: You have to define "query". Device discovery is another topic, http://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/tutorials/device-discovery.html

Comment: I know the address of the device, I just need to connect to the device and get values of various OIDs from the MIB that the device is using.Now with V1 and V2c, its simple, you just specify the community and you can get whatever value you want based on your MIB. But with V3, i found it a little tricky, there is no community parameter but there are many other parameters like context name , security name passphrase etc, I want to know in which case, which parameters are to be used. I hope I made myself a little more clear this time

Comment: contact the device administrators. What parameters are set initially are the ones you need to set in your queries. It is not something yourself can figure out magically.

Comment: Ok..so there is no other way to find those parameters value(like making some other request to the agent, and the agent replies with value) other than asking the administrators?

Comment: This is authentication. You don't ask websites for passwords , you provide them. You don't ask an agent for passwords, you provide them.

Answer (score 0):

The set of SNMPv3 parameters used to access the agent is the following:

- agent IP address/hostname
- UDP port (161 by default)
- username (security principal)
- security level (noAuthNoPriv, authNoPriv, authPriv)
- auth protocol (MD-5 or SHA-1)
- auth password
- priv protocol (CBC-DES, CFB-AES)
- priv password

That's it.